# How do I use EditAnywhere variables in the Actor constructor

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

In a class of a spaceship I have a variable `float CameraHeight` that defines how high a camera should be created above the mesh.

I want to set this variable in a Blueprint (based on the C++ class) so that I could *select the best value*. However, when I change this variable from Blueprint, the camera **does not** change its position. I believe that is because the constructor is only called when an object is created, and when I try to change the variable in the Blueprint, it **has already been** created, although I do not know how to solve that.

Is it even possible to set the camera height equal to a variable in C++ contructor, but to initialize the value of this variable only later, in the Blueprint?

***`ASpaceship.h`***

```
UCLASS()
class SPACESHIPSHOOTER_API ASpaceship : public ACharacter
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    ASpaceship();

protected:
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

    // Called to bind functionality to input
    virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent) override;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    float CameraHeight; // This variable

    UPROPERTY(EditDefaultsOnly)
    USkeletalMeshComponent* MeshComponent;

    UPROPERTY()
    UCameraComponent* CameraComponent;

    UFUNCTION()
    void MoveForward(float value);

    UFUNCTION()
    void MoveRight(float value);

};
```

***`ASpaceship.cpp constructor`***

```
ASpaceship::ASpaceship()
{
    // Set this character to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    MeshComponent = GetMesh();

    CameraComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCameraComponent>(TEXT("CameraComponent"));
    CameraComponent->SetupAttachment(MeshComponent);
    CameraComponent->SetRelativeLocation(FVector(0.0f, 0.0f, CameraHeight)); // Here I try to set the camera position with a variable
    CameraComponent->bUsePawnControlRotation = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, you can have a "construction script" functionality that will respond to any values you set in blueprint, if you add the following override:

```cpp
//.h
virtual void OnConstruction(const FTransform& Transform) override;

//.cpp
AYourActorClass::OnConstruction(const FTransform& Transform) {
   Super::OnConstruction(Transform);
   // Do whatever you want with the camera
}
```

The only important thing is, in your Blueprint's Construction Script, you need to call the Parent Construciton Script. Of you don't see the node for it, right click the construction script node, and select "add call to parent function".

Answer (score 0):

As @goose_lake said, it's an option to use `OnConstruction` function. But remember, that is called after the Blueprint’s components have been created and registered, so it won't work if you want to change some BP data.
If it's won't work, you cound use `UserConstructionScript` in your Blueprint instead. It's `BlueprintImplementableEvent` so it's called before.